# ayuda con codigo en c#

Tags: c#, .net

encontre una pagina para practicar programacion en c#, es muy interesante, se llama www.hackerrank.com, ellos me colocaron el siguiente ejercicio: Dada una matriz de enteros, encuentra la suma de sus elementos.

Por ejemplo, si la matriz,, por lo que devolver.

Función descriptiva

Complete la función simpleArraySum en el editor a continuación. Debe devolver la suma de los elementos de la matriz como un entero.

simpleArraySum tiene los siguientes parámetros:

ar: una matriz de enteros
Formato de entrada

La primera línea contiene un entero, que denota el tamaño de la matriz.
La segunda línea contiene enteros separados por espacios que representan los elementos de la matriz.

Restricciones

Formato de salida

Imprime la suma de los elementos de la matriz como un solo entero.

Entrada de muestra
6
1 2 3 4 10 11

Salida de muestra
31.

Ellos me dan el siguiente codigo, que debo de corregir para colocar el desafio que ellos me establecen:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {

/*
 * Complete the simpleArraySum function below.
 */
static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
    int size=ar.length
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

    int arCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] ar = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), arTemp => Convert.ToInt32(arTemp))
    ;
    int result = simpleArraySum(ar);

    textWriter.WriteLine(result);

    textWriter.Flush();
    textWriter.Close();
}
}
```

Me sale en error. Para probar mi logica, decidi hacer el codigo de cero, y alli si me da, aqui esta:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] vector;
            int valor=0;
            int x;
            Console.WriteLine("De el tamano del Vector");
            vector= new int[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
            for (x = 0; x < vector.Length; x++) {
                Console.WriteLine("De el valor de la posicion " + x);
                vector[x] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                valor = valor + vector[x];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("El valor es: " + valor);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Como debo de incluir el codigo que realice, a la porcion de codigo que ellos me piden? por favor ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui esta la respuesta correcta:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {

    /*
     * Complete the simpleArraySum function below.
     */
    static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
        int Result = 0;
        int size=ar.Length;
        int x;

   for (x = 0; x < size; x++){
    Result=Result+ar[x];
   }
   return Result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        int arCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] ar = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), arTemp => Convert.ToInt32(arTemp))
        ;
        int result = simpleArraySum(ar);

        textWriter.WriteLine(result);

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos Fabian solo debes hacer lo siguiente en la función que se llama Simple Array Sum

La cual es esta:

```
 static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
   int size=ar.length
    }
```

Solo debes poner tu código ahí te mostrare:

```
static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) 
{
   int size=ar.length;
   int Result = 0;

   for (x = 0; x < size; x++) 
            Result+=ar[x];

   return Result;

  }
```

Comment: Me sirvio tu aporte @David Bujosa, solo tuve que agregar los corchetes del for, pero del resto, sin problema!